# Change domain URL from https to http in a multisite Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, configuration, ssl, https, dns

I have a multisite Wordpress (3.0.5, but the problem persists since 3.0.0) install, in which I can see that the **domain URL** (from: Super admin/sites/Domain) is beginning with *https*, what I definitely do not like, as having a self-made cert, users always get an annoying error message from the browser.

I would like to set it to begin with a simple *http* but have no idea how to do that. I have looked though (I think) all options in the admin panel, I have checked the MySQL database also (xxx_blogs, xxx_sites, xxx_blognumber_options  -- in which *xxx* stands for my secret db prefix), but have no idea how to change that.

If I look into the Domains menu in Superadmin, I cannot even see my main domain, only others.

If anyone would have an idea to solve the issue, I would be very happy, as my page is quite useless sometimes (as loading e.g. images from *files* dir is just not working without accepting the security risk of using an untrusted cert).

Unfortunately buying a cert is not an option (thank to limited number of private IPs).

---

**Update**: I really do not find any options to set my domain name *without* https.

Though I have the followings in my site options:

```
Wordpress-https Internalurls    
Wordpress-https Externalurls = 0    
Wordpress-https Bypass = 0
Wordpress-https Disable Autohttps = 0
Wordpress-https Exclusive Https = 0
Wordpress-https Frontpage = 0
Wordpress-https Sharedssl = 0
Wordpress-https Sharedssl Host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched all sql entries in the database for the "domain name" (as was showed on Super Admin/Sites/Edit: "Domain") beginning with https  with all kind of greps and subs in all combination of my domain names, but did not found any static entry.

After all, I revised my wp_config.php and also tried to switch off `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` and `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` to totally disable SSL on the sites, but had no affect - I could only reach my admin pages just via SSL on port 443, which lead to review my Apache config.

**Solution:** the VirtualHost config file was screwed up somehow and the entry on port 80 also had some entries of SSLCertificate pointing to a self-signed cert. Sorry for the trouble folks!

Answer (score 1):

You're technically doing a site move here. You're going to need to update the site settings for all hosted sites in the database and posts, unfortunately.

According to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress):

"The best way to move Multisite is to move the files, edit the .htaccess (if the folder name containing Multisite changed), and then manually edit the database. Search for all instances of your domain name, and change them as needed. This step cannot yet be easily automated. If you're moving Multisite from one folder to another, you will need to make sure you edit the wp_blogs entries to change the folder name correctly."

In order to do the changes, you'd be much better off writing a program to return the matching entries from each field, replacing with a regex, and updating the row than trying to do it manually. Off the top of my head, I'd expect the bulk of the changes to be in the wp_options table.

Comment: Thank you @Zenham for your answer! I have checked *wp_options* table but could not find any entries by greping for *https://myblog.name*. Though the +1 is right for your answer :) I still do not know where to find this setting.